# Community Promotion Ads - 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads, site-promotion, top-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, on a gaming site, you might promote the following things:

- your ventrilo server
- the site's twitter account
- indie games that are awesome, but people might not know about
- game servers or gaming nights
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

> Unlike [Stack Overflow's similar initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011), you do *not* have to be advertising a free service, or libre software to take part in this initiative. Advertisements for non-free stuff is perfectly acceptable.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### Ad gallery

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1892).

Comment: As explained by [Jeff Atwood](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=626475#626475), please [direct complaints or concerns about the Community Promotion Ads to me in the associated discussion thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/community-promotion-ads-explanation-and-feedback). ♪

Comment: Love this idea! A good way for gamers to know little gems and for gamedevs to spread their work.

Comment: So, oddly enough, all of Gnomeslice's images seem ot have been borked.

Comment: @Raven > Maybe I don't know how to imgur correctly?  :S

Comment: It's now 2H 2011...

Comment: Not only is it 2H 2011, it's nearly Q4 (or the second half of 2H).

Answer (score 45):

[image: OpenTTD - Transport Tycoon for the 21st century]

Comment: I love openTTD (although I love its close competitor Simutrans too!) Trains - what can possibly be more fun than a big trainset!

Comment: A game like Minecraft that I keep coming back to, time after time.

Comment: I believe this ad is what first got me into OpenTTD.

Comment: It sure was for me :D

Comment: Yeah, Simutrans is pretty good too.

Answer (score 34):

[image: Download Desktop Dungeons - a Free Roguelike - today!]

Comment: Desktop Dungeons is *amazing*.

Comment: @LessPop I'm surprised there aren't more questions about it here.

Comment: @Mana Eh, really sometimes it seems like there's not so much to ask other than general strategy. "Who do I fight next?"

Comment: @badp True, I encountered this problem when immediately after that comment I thought hard about what kind of questions I could ask for DD and came up with absolutely nothing.

Comment: I just learned about DD yesterday. Found it on a site that listed top 2010 indy games. I fell in love with it instantly.

Comment: Thanks to this ad, I went to the DD site again and found out they now have a Mac version!

Comment: I lament the fact that there is no linux build available :(.

Comment: I love this game... Brilliant little "coffee break" time waster (I say waster in the nicest way possible, of course).

Answer (score 33):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: would it be possible for you to make one similar to this for the [StackExchange Steam group](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/stackexchange)?  Something similar with just a [Steam logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Steam_logo.svg) would be awesome.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Battle for Wesnoth: An open source turn-based game with a fantasy theme.]

Comment: I downloaded this a month or two ago after hearing about it on this site, but I only got around to playing it yesterday. I must say that it's the most polished and fun open-source game that I've ever seen.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Join Gaming Stack Exchange's BF3 server]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Yes, we do have a Ventrilo server. That's because we didn't know any better.]

Comment: Yay for Mumble!

Comment: Oooooh. Pick any *three*. Took me a sec.

Comment: Been using mumble for a few years now. +1 :)

Answer (score 21):

[image: We're playing games together twice every week! Come on in.]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Have Joel explain it to you.]

Comment: Basically, "copyright owners" would be able to ban a site from Google, all US traffic and all US payment services for having just a few "bad" links here and there.

Answer (score 20):

[image: You're adopted. Writing will make you feel better.]

Comment: Certainly looks pretty, but instead of it just pointing to the blog I reckon we need a "Contribute" page setting up for it to point to instead? Otherwise people will follow the link and just get lost...

Comment: Ok, which page do you think would be a better destination?

Comment: @Moshe: He's saying that we need a new, currently non-existent, page for it to link to.

Comment: Yes @Ullallulloo is correct, the gap lies elsewhere not with the advert, and it's one we really should plug. I'm going to see if I have permissions to create pages on the blog, if so we'll just need to decide what it should say...

Comment: @DMA57361, Ivo Flipse actually mentioned this to me yesterday. You might want to discuss with him, just so you're both on the same page. (No pun intended.)

Comment: I actually don't know how we added such a page on the SU blog, but I agree we need to add one.

Comment: @Ivo and Moshe - the blog lets us do it, I just tried it with a placeholder (and removed it again!), check my comments in [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/386/gaming-blog-editor-room)

Comment: Updated the link to [our brand new contribute page](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/contribute/)

Comment: @IvoFlipse - Great!

Comment: This ad always makes me think that glados wants to adopt me ("You're adopted!") as opposed to making me feel unloved ("You were adopted.")

Comment: @Nick, Your comment made me laugh. Awesome!

Answer (score 17):

[image: Classic games for Windows, DRM-free.]

Comment: Welcome, to **GOGCOM**!  This, is **GOGCOM**!  Anything can happen, at **GOGCOM**!

Comment: -1 for dumbest publicity stunt ever... http://www.itworld.com/business/121629/zone-alarm-and-gogcom-a-tale-two-marketing-blunders

Answer (score 15):

[image: Don't lose target! Write about what you want!]

Comment: Updated the link to [our brand new contribute page](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/contribute/)

Comment: @IvoFlipse Nice!

Answer (score 14):

[image: Join Stackexchange Gaming's Ventrilo Chat!]

Answer (score 13):

[image: The link to the blog is at the bottom!]

Comment: Poorly worded--how does the first statement (question) have anything to do with a blog?  Questions and answers belong on the Q&A site.  Posting good answers to your own real, useful questions on SE is perfectly valid.

Comment: @nick if you have a better line let's hear it. :)

Comment: @NickT I thought @badp meant it in a way that if you're bored and have nothing else to do: go write a blog post instead. But if you have a better wording, we're all ears :)

Answer (score 12):

[image: StackExchangeScripts - Help us help you help us all!]

Comment: Repost of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011/75018#75018

Comment: The resolution has been fixed, as well as what @badp said, though I think 'Get it now' isn't a particularly good tagline

Comment: How about replacing "Get it" with a 1 up mushroom?

Answer (score 11):

[image: WarMUX: An open-source artillery-style game with your favorite free software mascots!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Nitrome: Flash games with awesome pixel art, and chiptune music.]

Comment: Imgur seems to have broken this ad.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Team Fortress 2]

Comment: I said for a while I was going to post a TF2 ad, but never got around to it.  But here it is now!

Comment: I'm not the biggest fan of the image at the bottom, but Heavy is *the* iconic TF2 class.  I had one with a Spy fighting a Demoman and Soldier before, but eh...

Comment: I really feel that if we do advertise it's better to give it to open-source / indie projects. TF2 gets enough promotion without our help.

Comment: @Oak: While you may prefer it, "Unlike Stack Overflow's similar initiative, you do not have to be advertising a free service, or libre software to take part in this initiative. Advertisements for non-free stuff is perfectly acceptable."

Answer (score 7):

[image: Nippon. A trading game for iOS.]

Comment: Nippon is a classic trading game, remade for iOS.

Comment: I feel like this add need more text in some way.  I saw it, didn't know what it was, clicked it, and got taken to the itunes store (a place I did not want to be).

Answer (score 7):

[image: The 14th annual Independent Games Festival]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Solomon's Boneyard: A polished dual-stick shooter for iOS]

Comment: No idea, have an upvote. Is that your game?

Comment: @Moshe > No, but I just thought it was really good. :P

Answer (score 4):

[image: Harm's Way: A great multiplayer experience; FOR FREE!]

Comment: I thought this was the better of the two Doritos offerings.

Comment: @CyberSkull, make it three, now.  And yes, it's still the better.

Answer (score -12):

[Simply put a bare link to the video; it'll be replaced with the embedded player. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/Artwork/SO/Youtube%20embed%20ad.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71234/13992)

---

Bad things about this ad:

- **Off-topic**: it should've been a meta announcement instead.
- Size (this is a square 220×220, should've been 220×250, taller than it is wide)
- Poor use of color palette
- Overused, tired meme
- Too bland

Comment: This ad downvoted to hell because it's off-topic (a meta announcement would be more apt). Area51 teaches it's a good thing to have, actually, so please don't delete.