# Community Promotion Ads - Explanation and Feedback

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> This is an associated discussion thread for [Community Promotion Ads - 2011](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011), which is otherwise relegated towards posts actually for the ads.

Stack Overflow runs a [Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) system to host ad space on the sidebar of the main site. These are selected through a community voting process on Meta Stack Overflow, done in 6-month periods.

I would be happy to announce, had I actually been announcing it, that **Gaming Stack Exchange is now hosting a similar process for its own in-house advertising**. We're making motions towards increased promotion of the site, and our first step is reaching out.

Much of the basic detail is [covered in the ad post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011), so this is just a less concise clarification. Also, **if you have feedback, questions, concerns, or complaints to voice about this system, here would be a good place to post it**.

---

#### Where are the ads?

Ads that reach a sufficient score in the ad question will be hosted on the main Q&A site in the sidebar, as shown below. If you can't see any, you may be running a service or program that blocks advertisements on the Stack Exchange sites. This will prevent you from seeing these ads.

[image: Yay Desktop Dungeons! The space is between the chat house ad and the meta house ad.]

If you don't have anything running, these *do* share the ad space that is used for the Area 51 ads, and only one or the other will be shown. There isn't any sort of priority, so it may be bad luck on your refreshes. That said, if we can get a lot of ads into our cycle, it will probably improve the chances that these ads will show up instead. If you want to see these kinds of ads more than Area 51, suggest more. ♪

#### What is the purpose of the Community Promotion Ads?

I'll just quote Jeff for the opening here:

> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

This can be anything from community activities, to upcoming big gaming events and conventions, to advertising obscure games that more people need to learn about.

For example, some of the users host periodic game nights, which you can find out more information on [in the SE Game On! chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on). You could advertise upcoming games, with details on the event. Or you could just advertise that we do have these periodic get-togethers - your choice as to which you think will be more appealing. On another end, I've personally contacted certain indie localization groups who have recent as well as upcoming products, and will be working with them to supply some ads.

In the end, if it's something you think the members of the Gaming community and visitors of the site should be interested in, consider submitting your ad.

...

It's hard to really explain things without being totally redundant when Jeff's bullet list and Jin's sample ads did a fine job. Let's not waste your time with me ambling about then, if you have any more questions about this system, don't hesitate to ask. ♪

Answer (score 3):

Are adverts for non-free games acceptable here?  I can remove mine for *Solomon's Boneyard* if they are not.

Comment: Most gaming conferences and expositions are not free for admission, so I would say there is equally no restriction on game advertisements. The people I've contacted, for example, sell games. I'm personally fond of adverts for more obscure games - people coming to this site probably don't need to see yet another poster for Portal 2, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can I rotate the [OpenTTD ad](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/1930#1930) regularly with new ones with different background screenshots to keep it interesting?

Comment: I think that should be fine, as long as it isn't some kind of drastic change that would actually result in different opinions. I'll make an extra check just in case, but just a small background change around the same content should be rather permissible. And while I know you're not asking it, I'll just state the obvious that one should *not* change what is being adverted, or what is being linked to, post-vote.

Comment: @GraceNote Well, the image background image would be completely different because, well a 240x240 slice of the game just doesn't do it justice, and the same image gets boring after a while. The text will remain the same, but will probably be repositioned based on the background.. hang on, let me post what I think the new ads will look like