# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community PRomotion Ads - 2013](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Alright. We may have horribly failed to actually do a half-based Community Ads system last year. Well, this year, since we start in December to work on the actual year. Since it's more of a biseasonal thing. BUT ANYWAY... we may have failed to do half-based...

...and we're going to **continue** to fail to do it half-based! VIVA LA REVOLU... actually I'm not Spanish enough. So, at any rate, we're doing it by year now. Both as a measure of rebellion, and by official decree anyway.

We still have the [feedback post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/community-promotion-ads-explanation-and-feedback) for those who have questions, since there isn't a lot of good room here to respond.

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, on a gaming site, you might promote the following things:

- your ventrilo server
- the site's twitter account
- indie games that are awesome, but people might not know about
- game servers or gaming nights
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

> Unlike [Stack Overflow's similar initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011), you do *not* have to be advertising a free service, or libre software to take part in this initiative. Advertisements for non-free stuff is perfectly acceptable.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### Ad gallery

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3352).

Comment: So does this mean if we still want to use ads from last year that we have to resubmit them?

Comment: @Fallen You can reuse ads, but they ideally should have a new face and not just be a complete repost. Give it a fresh new feel, ideally. ♪

Answer (score 37):

[image: Community Ads with Gaming.SE]

Comment: Feel free to downvote if recursion is frowned upon...

Comment: [Jeff seems not to mind.](http://meta.superuser.com/a/2281/16987)

Comment: Needs more Comic Sans.

Answer (score 33):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Answer (score 32):

[image: Join the Arqade Community on Steam!]

Comment: Visually appealing and fits the site theme nicely, well done.

Answer (score 26):

[image: It's really a no-brainer. Get it now.]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Contribute to the Gaming Community Blog!]

Comment: FYI, we have [a page designed to be linked to in this context](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/contribute/).  Might be better than a meta thread.

Comment: Thanks @John - changed.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Stackgaming's survival Minecraft server]

Comment: Thank you for nothing the problem with image-only posts; this has been rectified

Comment: It looks like the mouseover text has a typo, survival is spelled survial. Pretty minor, but I just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Combine OverWiki, the Half-Life and Portal wiki - Run. Think. Shoot. Edit.]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Nuclear Dawn is a Source engine based Multiplayer game that combines the visceral action of a First Person Shooter with the deep branching gameplay of a Real Time Strategy title.]

Comment: InterWave Studios is an indie dev house that released Nuclear Dawn on Steam in 2011 - they're looking to promote it on the site, and there might be a cool giveaway coming soonish :)

Comment: Game is dead. Don't buy it. There is maybe 1 server that has players sometimes and they are very elitist, telling you to leave if you don't have a good k/d right away.

Answer (score 13):

[image: The epistemology, ethics, and metaphysics of cakes]

Comment: Support a friendly beta! *Spread the knowledge!*

Comment: "The" should be "the" IMO; I'd also push the "Click here" line down a bit.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks! I took the advice.

Comment: -1, Hobo Standard font.  Real original.  But mostly because it doesn't scream 'philosophy' at me.

Comment: This ad really needs the text `philosophy.stackexchange.com` in it.  As it stands, it's disingenuous in that it appears to be a site about Portal 2 *(which would appeal to many gamers)*.  Meanwhile, the people who would *actually* be interested in a philosophy site, but not Portal 2, will most likely not click on this ad.  -1.

Comment: I would change the "Click here to be enlightened" to "philosophy.stackexchange.com".  It would also be sweet if there were a relevant question behind the link rather than just the front page.

Comment: Nice changes. - Changed my thumbs down to a thumbs up!

Comment: white on light blue makes it hard to read

Comment: To be frank, I liked the original one a lot better than this.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Professional Starcraft 2 strategy & commentary]

Comment: This is an amazing webshow :)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Visit the new Chess Stack Exchange site]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Faster than Light]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Run. Think. Shoot. Live. Source]

Comment: "They're waiting for you, Gordon." flows a bit better IMO.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Scientist. Fictional.]

Comment: There's already one for scifi.stackexchange

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The Gandalf one is a generic ad for scifi/fantasy, while this tells you "hey, we also love video-game lore!". A different thing. Tailored just for Arqade.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Compete on 4 new maps every day]

Comment: Neat, +1 even though I have no idea what this is.

Comment: +1 because after discovering this *completely free* game, I enjoyed it so much that I contacted the creator and suggested he post here :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Why "Ask" and not "ask"?

Comment: How is a wizard Sci-fi? Surely Wizard is Fantasy cadre?

Comment: Having now visited the site, I see that it's actually Sci-fi *and* fantasy!

Answer (score 5):

[image: A classic game. Now stunning on iPod and iPad.]

Comment: Needs a tagline.

Comment: Good call. Fixed.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  Is it against the rules to advertise your own work?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Ask your lore questions on scifi.stackexchange]

Answer (score -3):

[image: The Blops]

Comment: Self-promotion warning. I hope you like it!

Comment: Lots of downvotes, any tip on how it would be better accepted?

Comment: Some indication of why the community should stand behind *this particular* iOS puzzle game instead of the millions of competing games might help.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie But most ads just use an image and a short non-descriptive tagline (because they are already famous). I feel that writing more would make a worse ad.

Comment: Yes, conflicts between what makes an ad attract upvotes indicating community support and what makes an ad effective advertising are possible. Perhaps the lack of famousness requires a different advertising and community-support-garnering approach than ads for things the community already knows and supports. tl;dr: an effective ad knows its audience(s).

Comment: OK, I'll look for a better way to advertise and meanwhile I'll leave this ad here in case it becomes famous. Thanks for the help!