# We Need To Add Ask More About Slender Games Into Arqade

Tags: discussion

I was thinking, we really need to ask more about Slenderman Games on this site!  I mean how many of you play any Slender game like The 8 Pages, Haunt, The Arrival and so many more?  These games are so popular yet they aren't on this site!  I just want people to start to ask more questions and-if you have enough reputation- add more tags about the Slender games! :)

Never heard of these games?  Here is the link to the official site of the first ever slender game! http://www.parsecproductions.net/slender/

Comment: There's a one-man solution to this problem that you can implement on your own. Ask some questions about the games!

Comment: Wow I suck at asking question on this site...

Comment: We don't ask questions because we need questions. We ask them because we want answers.

Comment: "These games are so popular yet they aren't on this site!" + no link to the games. That keeps them kinda unknown to us now doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry about that...

Comment: Who are 'we'? Why should I ask question about a game, when i don't have a question to start with? That doesn't actually make any logical sense.

Answer (score 5):

[With very few exceptions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/adult-themed-gaming), We don't have any special treatment of game genres. If a user has a question about a video game, regardless of the genre, that user is welcome to ask.

Now, if you think a certain genre fits the Q&A format but is still underrepresented here, your best bet is to advertise the existence of this site on forums and other communities that deal with that genre; coming *here* and saying "let's ask about these" is unlikely to do much.

Additionally, if a new game comes out soon that you think would be popular and could potentially send a lot of traffic here, regardless of the genre, you're welcome to suggest a promotion event.

Finally, you might be interested in [this related answer of mine on the topic of artificially trying to add interest in games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4838/122).

Comment: That said I just don't think these games lend themselves to q&a really

Comment: @badp honestly I don't even know what that genre is

Answer (score 1):

The popularity of a game is not necessarily proportionate to the number of questions you have on it.  While I have never played the Slender games, it could be that they are straight-forward enough that the player never gets confused on where to go or what to do.

For example, Tetris is a popular game but is simple.  Blocks drop, you get a row filled, they disappear.  There is not much to ask about in such a game.

Also, with many games like Slender, story tends to be a fairly integral part of the story (Amnesia, Silent Hill).  Asking a question here may lead to spoilers.