# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- your ventrilo server
- the site's twitter account
- indie games that are awesome, but people might not know about
- game servers or gaming nights
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5602).

Answer (score 33):

[image: Child's Play - Give games to kids in hospital]

Answer (score 27):

[image: Join the Arqade Community on Steam!]

Comment: Steam says: Sorry!
An error was encountered while processing your request:"No group could be retrieved for the given URL."

Comment: @rlb.usa Try it again; works fine for me.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Kerbal Space Program]

Comment: +1, everyone should play this.

Comment: I woulda captioned it "Not exactly rocket surgery", but then I like Ed Yong's blog :)

Answer (score 19):

[image: Mumble: open source, low-latency, high quality voice chat]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Raspberry Pi]

Comment: +1, but you forgot [Super NES](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2984)

Comment: isn't this a bit unrealistic? What links do you have that supports Gamecube?

Answer (score 16):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: Isn't this logo a little out of date?

Comment: @GnomeSlice PIXELATED HEART 4 LYFE

Comment: @GnomeSlice Yes, yes it is. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Pathery]

Comment: +1 this is my favorite free (actually-free, not farmville-free) browser-based game

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes, it's a great game, and worthy recipient of ad space.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Skeptics.SE: a free, community driven Q&A for scientific skepticism.]

Comment: I thought this was gonna lead me to some question. What's it a reference to?

Comment: @JNat Portal, and an ad we had last year.

Comment: Ewwwwwwwwwwrgh.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Anime and Manga SE]

Comment: We decided over at [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com) that we will rotate the image that appears here, so that we can show all our ads without 'flooding' your site with them. Thus, we will change the image on the post every week or so.

Comment: I just saw this ad - wonderful!

Comment: And it has never been edited since.

Comment: I really don't like the idea of rotating ads. We vote on the specific ad proposed, not on the general "idea" of an ad.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Minecraft Feed The Beast Arqade Community Server]

Comment: I made this ages ago, and @JeffreyLin's post reminded me to post it :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's way better than mine. Which I probably deserved the downvotes for.

Comment: I updated the link to point at a Meta post that describes the server, rather than the wasteland that is Minecraft chat.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Subscribe to Arqade Community on YouTube]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Scientist. Fictional.]

Comment: Brought to you by the [year 2012](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5348/10310).